# Is there a word that means "make someone (or something) redundant"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, by improving some system, some function is now redundant. So the improvement XXX that function.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Comment: I would re-word it to say "The function is now obsolete because of the improvements".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you aren't replacing the old function by a new one (i.e., a function is no longer required) then you may prefer *obviate*, as in "this feature obviates the need to call XXX" or "new procedures obviate the need for a dedicated XXX department."

Or *obsolete* may be used as a verb, like "this feature obsoletes the XXX function" – although I'd definitely avoid calling *a person* obsolete.

But if you can say "XXX is now called automatically when needed," I'd go with that.

Comment: *obviate the need for* [is more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=obviates+the+need+for%2Cremoves+the+need+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) as a "set phrase" than *remove the need for*, but I don't really see the point it. The relatively obscure word *obviate* would probably be almost unknown if it weren't forever obviating **needs** - you don't often find it obviating anything else. I think it's just a somewhat pompous cliched alternative to "remove".

Comment: Well, there is [some debate](http://www.theatlantic.com/past/issues/99mar/wdct9903.htm) over it, but *obviate* may be used without the *need for* part.

Comment: When not followed by "need", *obviate* usually has a somewhat different meaning - akin to *anihilates* or *denies the possibility of*, rather than *removes the need for*. And to be honest, I find that usage somewhat archaic.

Comment: @fumble do you have a citation or reference for the statement that "obviate when not followed by 'the need for' usually means *annihilate* or *denies the possibility of*"?

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: No citation, I'm afraid. But apart from the fact that I already thought it, that seemed to be the sense of the first half-dozen [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q="obviates"&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) entries I looked at for **obviates** that *weren't* followed by "the need/necessity/etc."

Comment: ...on reflection, I think probably people simply assume that meaning because the word is unfamiliar outside the somewhat tautological *"obviate the need for"*. People don't normally learn words from dictionary definitions - they take note of how the word is *used*. Which in the case of "obviate" could well lead to conflation with the more well-known "obliterate".

Comment: @fumble it is definitely true that "obviates" not alongside "the need for" is much rarer than I realized; it's probably fair to call this a stronger phrase than a standalone word. Not convinced as to the change of meaning when alone, though..

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I think you are in fact correct. There were so few examples of "obviated" without "need/necessity" that I read too much into the fact that of the first half-dozen I found, at least a couple would probably have been unaffected if not clearer by substituting, perhaps, *"demolished"*. On checking more closely I see that these are abberant cases. Most people who use it "standalone" obviously agree with [Barbara Wallraff](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qYU4-hBZLkAC&q=%22obviates%22&dq=%22obviates%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KQ3xTp3rII6yhAe3jtWjAQ&redir_esc=y) that it is sufficient in itself!

Answer (score 7):

I would say that the new *supersedes* the old.

Comment: *Subsume* also works here, but I don't think that is the question being asked.

Answer (score 4):

In British English, the construction "make  redundant" is itself a common one.

For example, someone laid off in a company restructuring might say "I've been made redundant."

And the American English equivalent when persons are the object is *downsized*.

e.g. "When Acme, Inc. closed its Spartanburg factory, some 50,000 local workers were downsized".

Comment: I have never understood the usage "made redundant". If there are two people in one role (such as when a merger happens - you don't need 2 Vice Presidents) then it is actually *preventing* redundancy to let one person go. Also, as a computer programmer, I wanted "redundancy" in the sense that someone else could do my job when I was on vacation. Redundancy prevents critical failures. It is not the word to blame on losing your job! Redundancy is a Good Thing. A British friend does not understand the usage "let go", he thinks it sounds like I wanted to leave the job and they allowed me to!

Answer (score 4):

*Deprecate* in computer science is defined as:

> declare obsolescence of something: to state that a computational method or computer feature is superseded.
>    - Microsoft® Encarta® 2009

Because one of the meanings of obviate is "to make unnecessary," it is sometimes argued that obviate the need (or necessity) for is redundant. An older but still current meaning, however, is "to avoid an anticipated difficulty." In a sentence like Addressing these issues early can obviate any need for a joint resolution, the need can be perceived as a difficulty - or early consideration can make the resolution unnecessary, in which case any need for is indeed redundant. There is little reason to prefer either interpretation to the other, except that substitution of to make unnecessary allows much the same thought to be expressed with fewer words. 
same source.

Comment: Does something *deprecate* some other thing in the sense of superseding or obviating?

Comment: @Kris It tends to be used as "Old feature A has _been deprecated by_ new feature B."

Comment: @IQAndreas http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a direct, one-for-one replacement of the old by the new, why not simply use ***replace***? *Supercede*, as Barrie suggested, also works in this sense.

If, on the other hand, it it just a side effect that the old function is not needed any more, then I would vote with @rdhs on *obviate*.

Answer (score 1):

> We wanted to redundify our network so we added another firewall in HA mode.

**redundify** in Urban Dicationary:
[LINK](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=redundify)

Answer (score 0):

If OP is looking for a single word, I don't know one in common parlance. Increasingly, we say [removes the need for](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=removes%20the%20need%20for&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) XXX...

[image]