# What's a word for "to eliminate the need for"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a word that means “make someone (or something) redundant”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52112/is-there-a-word-that-means-make-someone-or-something-redundant)

I'm looking for a word that I can use in a context where I say something like

> If you let me look in your garage it will **eliminate the need for** a warrant.

Even if I have to rearrange the sentence, I wouldn't mind.

Comment: .. _there'll be no need for a warrant; I won't need a warrant; there's no requirement for a warrant; a warrant isn't required._

Comment: @FumbleFingers While both questions share one similar answer, IMO they are sufficiently distinct from each other.

Comment: @coleopterist: Maybe you see a difference, but I think if there was one you'd be splitting splitting hairs to identify it. Regardless of that, your own *dispense* is way off base, since it's impossible to use that in OP's example construction without the radical change of switching the subject of the verb from *the act of looking in the garage* to *what **we** will be able to do if that act takes place*.

Comment: "The other quickest way to develop talent, job rotate their bosses and elevate the next line. Redundantify!" http://www.twylah.com/JoyAndLife/tweets/204951152847110144

Comment: "You can ensmallen and de-redundantify the file by removing anything that isn't part of Group 0x01xxxxxx" http://www.moreawesomethanyou.com/smf/index.php?topic=18888.1975;wap2 --- Look for redundancies and un-redundantify your copy! http://omars-jrn200blog.blogspot.in/2012/10/murder-do-you-need-to-say.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Obviate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obviate): to bypass a requirement or make it unnecessary.

Comment: That doesn't actually work here.  You'd still have to say "obviate the need for a warrant" -- they even use it that way in the wiktionary link.

Comment: This is the kind of word that I am looking for. Thank you very much, .

Comment: You're welcome. Note that as @starwed noted, you would still need to use "the need for" as in "obviate the need for a warrant."

Comment: Do you *really* need "the need for" or is that superfluous speech, like "the car was traveling at a high *rate of speed*" rather than "at a high speed" or "fast"? If obviate means to make unnecessary, then "obviate the need" means "make unnecessary the need" which is silly. How about: "When a criminal is caught red-handed, the circumstances obviate the arrest warrant."

Comment: @Kaz. Interesting, there seems to be some disagreement! Your comment and starwed's both have two upvotes.

Comment: In any case, it might be worth starting a movement to obviate "the need" in "obviate the need". :)

Comment: *Obviate* needs *the need*. Else use the *-ing* form. http://books.google.co.in/books?id=woG3lgxxDtIC&pg=PA31&dq=obviate+need+OR+necessity&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JUv6UNnoBZHzrQf_uIGoAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=obviate%20need%20OR%20necessity&f=false

Comment: You cannot have an *-ing* form of a noun like *warrant*, though.

Comment: is there any difference between *obviate* and *eliminate*?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of word I was looking for. Thank you JAM!

Answer (score 7):

If the sentence can be reworded slightly, you could say,

> If you let me look in your garage we can **dispense** with the warrant.

[Dispense](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dispense):

> [with object] **(dispense with)** manage without or get rid of:
>   *let’s dispense with the formalities, shall we?*
>
> give special exemption from (a law or rule):
>   *the Secretary of State was empowered to dispense with the nationality requirement in individual cases*

Comment: Would it be "dispense with" or just "dispense"?

Comment: @YertJones It would be "dispense with" as in the examples from the dictionary. The meaning changes sans _with_.

Answer (score 3):

**Preclude**: ‘To prevent (an action, event, situation) from taking place, esp. in advance; to remove the possibility of (an event, etc.) occurring, to make impossible; to rule out.’

Comment: That's to eliminate *possibility*, not need.