# Formal alternatives for: "There is not a need"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, formality

I am writing a formal technical report and I would like some advice about an expression I want to use. I have a sentence which I want to make more formal:

> The merit of their  approach is that **there is not a need** of designing  a fusion strategy for the several modalities.

Basically I want to change the ‘there is not a need for’ to something more formal.   Any suggestions?

Comment: ...that it does not necessitate a fusion strategy for the several modalities?

Comment: Somebody confirm, but shouldn't it be "...there is not a need **to design**..."

Comment: The second request says: "not a need **for**" but in the quote it is: not a need **of**". The former flows better.

Comment: Seems pretty formal already. But, for the sake of clarity, you could write "...it is not necessary to design a fusion strategy..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I want to change the ‘there is not a need for’ to something more formal.

"The merit of their approach is that it **circumvents the necessity** of designing ..."

> **circumvent** *verb*: find a way around (an obstacle).
>
> • overcome (a problem or difficulty), typically in a clever and surreptitious way. "I found it quite easy to *circumvent* security";
>
> *synonyms*: avoid, get around, get past, evade, bypass, sidestep, dodge; *informal* duck; "the checkpoints were easy to *circumvent*"; Google [circumvent](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=circumvent+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 4):

> > The merit of their  approach is that **there is not a need** of designing  a fusion strategy for the several modalities.

In general the determiner "*no*" can be more concise than a combination of a negated auxiliary and *a*. In other words *There is no need* might be more elegant here than "*There is not a need*". Secondly, the noun *need* normally takes preposition phrases headed by the preposition *for* or infinitival clauses. So the Original Poster's sentence might read better thus:

> The merit of their  approach is that **there is no need to design** a fusion strategy for the several modalities.

Answer (score 1):

> The merit of their approach is that *it eliminates the need for*
>   multiple/several fusion strategies.

Or to the extent that my rewording changes the meaning too much:

> …*eliminates the need to* design/*for* designing a [different/separate] fusion
>   strategy for [each of] the several modalities.

(For other good alternatives to “eliminates the need [for/to],” see the answers to this somewhat related question: 
[What's a word for "to eliminate the need for"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100537/whats-a-word-for-to-eliminate-the-need-for))

Answer (score 1):

What about "Obviates the need"?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).